# StaleElementReferenceException when trying to reidentify the object

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem to identify the object when i move forward and comeback to parent page.

Here is the scenario. I would like to click on each link in a home page and print page title and navigate back to home page.

Following is the code which i tried. It works fine clicking on the first link and coming back to HomePage. At this point of time, the List Object needs to be identified excluding already visited links. How to do that?

In QTP, we have RefreshObject and Init to do this. Is there a similar method in WebDriver?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.googl.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

List<WebElement> objWEs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElement e:objWEs)
{
    if(!e.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        e.click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
}
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you navigate to another web-page, or even switch into an `iframe` in the same web-page, any `WebElement` object that you have in memory is potentially "stale".

One optional solution, is to list down all the element IDs, and then iterate that list instead:

```
Set<String> linkIds = new HashSet<String>();
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    if(!link.getText().isEmpty())
        linkIds.add(link.getAttribute("id"));
}
for (String linkId : linkIds)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id(linkId)).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Please note, however, that all the above is under the assumption that each link has a unique ID, and that all the links remain in the web-page when you navigate back into it. If this is not the case in the specific web-page that you are accessing, then an alternative approach is required here.

Instead of iterating the link-IDs, you can iterate the link-indexes, assuming that the links **remain in the same order** when you navigate in and out of the web-page. This is somewhat less efficient though, because you have to retrieve the entire list of all the links at the beginning of each iteration.

```
for (int i=0; true; i++)
{
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    if (i >= links.size())
        break;
    links.get(i).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

The code above should work **even if the links do not remain in the same order** when you navigate back into the web-page. However, under such scenario, you will most likely miss out on some of them.

Comment: For your first approach, can i copy all list values into another object and retrieve by index and perform operation? Can you please help me how to copy this list of WebElements to another List?

Comment: @Uday: That's exactly what I'm doing in the first approach. The `linkIds` object contains all the values, and instead of retrieving those values by index, I iterate them using `for (String linkId : linkIds)`.

Comment: i understand your logic, but you need to rely on Ids. So my thought is copy the objs. and retrieve by index. In this way you need not rely on any other properties/attributes. Am i make sense or i am thinking too foolish(FYI... I am very new to Java)?

Comment: @Uday: As I mentioned at the top of the answer, once you navigate to another web-page, you can no longer rely on any `WebElement` object that you had in memory prior to the navigation. There is no way to "store" `WebElement` objects, and that's why you have to "find" them again once you're back in the original web-page. For that, you need to use one of their attributes, which you **CAN** save (in an array of strings for example) before navigating.

Comment: Yeah, got it, but my problem still exists as there is no unique identifier. As in this example, how can i do it? There is no id field, and class is not quire for all links. So trying to capture with text, but the limitations are same link name should not exist. Is this is correct?             if(!link.getText().isEmpty())
                linkIds.add(link.getAttribute("text"));

Comment: @Uday: Well try the second option then.

Comment: 2nd approach is bit tricky and easy to understand. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Adding the complete code below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for my above problem.

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        driver.get("http://www.googl.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        for (int i=0; true; i++)
        {
            List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            if (i >= links.size())
                break;
            WebElement ele=links.get(i);
            if(!ele.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                ele.click();
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                driver.navigate().back();
            }
        }

        driver.close();
```